# SQL builder gui for mysql

Tags: mysql

HI I want to how a gui for building my queries. It would be nice for it to have syntax validation. Ie if I have a missing quote it'll tell me. It balances brackets. It's simple but very easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_list.php). Free community edition, paid enterprise edition with great features such as Query Profiling, Synchronization, Advanced Connectivity. see also http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/217884 .

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out Toad for MySQL at [here](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/). The doc says its a free ware. I guess this will address most of your problems

Comment: just checked this out - impressive! best of the 4 programs mentioned so far. and free indeed.

Comment: bit a of learning curve, but it looks like its the only one to feature auto-completion and multiple tabs

Answer (score 1):

Heidi SQL

[heidi sql on the web](http://www.heidisql.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use ***NaviCat*** You can find those on [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com)